# ReactJS как в return написать js + reactjs код?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, render

При рендере мне нужно сделать проверку. Попробовал так

```
render() {
    return (
      <table border="1" width="500px">
        <tr>
          <td>Название</td>
          <td>Категория</td>
          <td>Цена (шт.)</td>
          <td>
            Кол-во <button onClick={this.sortProducts}>сортировка</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
{
if (state.filters.isFruitChecked) {
  state.products.filter(e => e.category == "fruit")
  .map(product => (
    <tr>
      <td>{product.name}</td>
      <td>{product.category}</td>
      <td>{product.price}</td>
      <td>{product.amount}</td>
    </tr>
  ))
}
}
</table>
    );
  }
```

Он мне выводит что if это синтаксическая ошибка. Подскажите как мне написать проверку правильно?

Comment: всё верно. в jsx нельзя использовать `if`. точнее, его там просто нет

Comment: @Август можно как нибудь по другому сделать? Например если условие поместить внутрь filter это просто для примера, то он отрабатывает if.

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
    return (
      <table border="1" width="500px">
        <tr>
          <td>Название</td>
          <td>Категория</td>
          <td>Цена (шт.)</td>
          <td>
            Кол-во <button onClick={this.sortProducts}>сортировка</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {
          state.filters.isFruitChecked &&     //  через конъюнкцию (&&)
          state.products.
            filter(e => e.category == "fruit").
            map(product => (
              <tr>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>{product.amount}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        }
      </table>
   );
}
```